# sagemaker-sklearn-container 1.0 requires pandas==0.25.*, but you have pandas 1.3.5 which is incompatible

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dependencies, amazon-sagemaker

**ERROR:** pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

`sagemaker-sklearn-container 1.0 requires pandas==0.25.*,` but you have `pandas 1.3.5` which is incompatible.

I am running my notebook locally under python virtual machine , and I have `pandas 0.25.3` version but when I am training the model on sagemaker , it shows an error that amazon scikitlearn container `1.0 using 0.25.*` but I have `1.3.5`,

I don't understand how can I solve it , though locally I have `0.25.3`

Comment: did you resolve this issue?
i need functionality from a more advanced python version, and not sure how to adapt the sagemaker estimator for it to work

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, You can use you training script to uninstall and install the required version of Pandas.

For example

```
import os 
os.execute('pip ...')
```

To speed up experimenting this workaround, you can use SageMaker local mode.

You can apply the same workaround while deploying the model by using the `inference.py` script.

Otherwise, you can extend the scikit-learn container and install the desired version of Pandas. The [example here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/35e2faf7d1cc48ccedf0b2ede1da9987a18727a5/advanced_functionality/pytorch_extending_our_containers) explains how to extend the pre-built containers.